# Get battery information in android

Tags: android, android-service

Is there any ways in android to get information like which active application is using how much battery?

For example I have 3 active application 
1) Yelp
2) Facebook
3) Google maps

So what i want is what % of battery currently Yelp, Facebook and Google maps  is occupying ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The app "BetterBatteryStats" does that. I don't know how it's implemented, but it's open source, so you can look at the source code here :

https://github.com/asksven/BetterBatteryStats